# Need Latex compilation for only some eps files, want rest as precompiled pdfs or png

Tags: pdftex, eps

I am using the `chemscheme` package and in order to replace numbering in these schemes I have in my document, I need to compile those eps files with latex, then dvips, and finally ps2pdf.

However, I have a very large number of images (upwards of 100, and it will only be increasing) that are perfectly fine to be used as the png they are in, or a precompiled pdf file.  Since I need latex compilation for the `chemscheme` numbering, all those png or pdf images need to be in eps form, and it adds a solid 2-3 minutes to the compilation time.

Is there any solution for this type of situation?

I have read some solutions on here about packages like `standalone` and `externalize` but I confess to not fully understanding how to apply those solutions or if they even apply to this situation.

I thought I would add that without these extra images, my latex file compiles in about 30 secs, with the images it is now almost at 4 minutes compilation time :(

Here is an example of how the `chemscheme` package works (it is included as part of the `chemstyle` package.  The file "reaction.eps" can be downloaded at the following link.  The zip file also includes what the png looks like if you precompile it just on it's own (those TMP tags get replaced during the conversion process).  The numbering commands `\CNlabel` and `\CNlabelsub` are sprinkled throughout the document, and they increment counters related to the compound numbering which is used in the replacement of the `TMP` tags within the images.  However, only a handful of my images use these tmp tags and require this certain compilation.  The rest have no `TMP` included and can be compiled externally without problem.  In order to get the correct numbering, `latex` must be run twice, before calling `dvips`.

eps and pdf files:  http://www.filedropper.com/reaction_1

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{bpchem}
\usepackage[tracking=bpchem]{chemstyle}


\begin{document}

I am a document about methanol (\CNlabelsub{alcohol}{Me}), and the related alcohol isoamyl %
alcohol (\CNlabelsub{alcohol}{isoamy}).  \CNlabelsub{alcohol}{Me} can be converted to an alkyl %
halide with \BPChem{HCl} to give chloromethane (\CNlabel{MeCl}, \ref{sch:reaction}).
\begin{scheme}
\caption{I am a scheme}\label{sch:reaction}
\schemerefsub{alcohol}{Me}
\schemerefsub{alcohol}{isoamy}
\schemeref{MeCl}
\includegraphics{reaction}
\end{scheme}

\end{document}
```

**Update, possible solution, but not quite finished**

From Garbage Collector's answer, it did occur to me.  I can provide a premade list of all the compounds in the document with a command `\CNlabelnoref` and `\CNlabelsubnoref`.  I have done that, and below is a MWE using the standalone package.  However, I now get an error a whole list of errors beginning at the `\begin{figure}` line, the first one being

> LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

```
\documentclass[border=0pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{bpchem}
\usepackage[journal=rsc,tracking=bpchem]{chemstyle}
\renewcommand*{\schemerefformat}{\small\fontfamily{cmr}}
\newcommand{\chemdrawgraphic}[1]{\includegraphics[scale=1]{#1}}
\setcounter{BPCno}{200}
\CNlabelsubnoref{alcohol}{Me}
\CNlabelsubnoref{alcohol}{isoamy}
\CNlabelnoref{MeCl}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \schemerefsub{alcohol}{Me}
    \schemerefsub{alcohol}{isoamy}
    \schemeref{MeCl}
    \chemdrawgraphic{reaction}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `externalize` seems to mean the `external` library of `tikz`. That seems to be unrelated to `chemscheme` (at least tikz is not listed in its package dependencies).

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger This would be my indication of not fully understanding how to use those libraries :)  hence looking for some guidance and a possible to solution to my problem

Comment: @JM -- why do you need to run latex rather than pdflatex?    pdflatex wouldn't require any change to the png files.  if the requirement excludes pdf output, the thing would be to use make to decide which eps needs changing since last compilation.

Comment: @wasteofspace The `chemscheme` package uses temporary text holders in the eps file which are later replaced during the compilation ps conversion with numbers from the document.  Compilation directly to pdf bypasses this and result in the temporary text holders not being replaced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compile each of `diagram.tex` files with `latex-dvips-pspdf` to get `diagram.pdf`.

```
% diagram.tex
\documentclass[border=0pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemscheme}
\begin{document}
% do your drawing
\end{document}
```

From within your main input file, import the `diagram.pdf` and other PNG, JPG, PDF images with `\includegraphics`. Compile the main input file with `pdflatex`.

Comment: Unfortunately this will not work for the use of these documents.  I've included an example of how `chemscheme` (which is included as part of the `chemstyle` package) works.  Throughout the document there are those `\CNlabel` numbering commands so the compilation of the standalones must be aware of those numberings.

Comment: I've updated my question, and provided a new MWE.  I have compiled a list of my compound references for use in standalone environments.  However, I am now getting an error when I try to use the `\begin{figure}` command.  Under my update is a new MWE.  It uses the same eps file I have linked to in the post.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the temperary textholders when using `pdfLatex`, too. See for example this question: [Chemnum/PS-Frag with EPS-Files and PNG-Files](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142277/chemnum-ps-frag-with-eps-files-and-png-files?noredirect=1#comment321890_142277)

From what I remember, `chemscheme` and `chemnum` do - in principle - the same thing when it comes to numbering of compounds in the text and in schemes or figures, so what has been said in the question mentioned above, should also apply in your case.

I have been using `pdfLatex` for some time with eps and png figures and it works fine, if you don't change font size dramatically.

Here I the MWE from the link above, that - however - uses `chemnum` instead:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Modern font encoding
%\usepackage{pstool}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage[crop=off]{auto-pst-pdf} % Use EPS graphics with pdfLaTeX
\usepackage{booktabs} % Better table layouts
\usepackage[journal=rsc]{chemstyle} % Of course!
\usepackage{geometry} % Easy page layout
\usepackage{lmodern} % Use Latin Modern fonts
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem} % Formula subscripts using \ce{}
\usepackage{xkeyval}
\usepackage{pst-pdf}
\usepackage{ifplatform}

\begin{document}
Test Test
\begin{figure} %% eps
\centering
\psfrag{goldhydrid}{test}
\includegraphics[scale=1.0]{./someeps}
\caption{A Caption}
\label{fig:someeps}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure} %% pngfile
\centering
\psfrag{goldhydrid}{test}
\includegraphics[scale=1.0]{./pngfile}
\caption{A Caption}
\label{fig:pngfile}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```