# Standalone with \begin{figure} gives error

Tags: standalone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to use the figure environment with the standalone package?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15414/is-it-possible-to-use-the-figure-environment-with-the-standalone-package)

After the suggested answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/69657/16782).  I've gone ahead to try and implement that for my own project.  However, I get an error stating:

> LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

Here is a full MWE below:

```
\documentclass[border=0pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{bpchem}
\usepackage[journal=rsc,tracking=bpchem]{chemstyle}
\renewcommand*{\schemerefformat}{\small\fontfamily{cmr}}
\newcommand{\chemdrawgraphic}[1]{\includegraphics[scale=1]{#1}}
\setcounter{BPCno}{200}
\CNlabelsubnoref{alcohol}{Me}
\CNlabelsubnoref{alcohol}{isoamy}
\CNlabelnoref{MeCl}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \schemerefsub{alcohol}{Me}
    \schemerefsub{alcohol}{isoamy}
    \schemeref{MeCl}
    \chemdrawgraphic{reaction}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

However, I also get the error with the following MWE

```
\documentclass[border=0pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics{reaction}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The documentation states that you can use floats now with the updated packaged.  In any case, I found removing the `\begin{figure}` portion allowed for the compilation, as suggested in that answer.

Comment: Also you have to add `preview` option to the class declaration.