# Chemnum/PS-Frag with EPS-Files and PNG-Files

Tags: pdftex, psfrag, chemnum

In my research report, I would like to include both, EPS files to achieve automatic numbering of my compounds in schemes with `chemnum` and also PNG files to include 3D structures of my molecules. I have tried several approaches, and am able to automatically number my compounds with a `latex`->`dvi`->`ps`->`pdf` workflow using EPS files for my reactions. However, I am not able to include a PNG file in the same document. What is the right approach for this?

Unfortunately, there is no way to get around the PNG files, as they are made by another programme necessary for visualization.

I have tried this example:

```
    \documentclass[a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Modern font encoding
    %\usepackage{pstool}
    \usepackage{psfrag}
    \usepackage[runs=2]{auto-pst-pdf} % Use EPS graphics with pdfLaTeX
    \usepackage{booktabs} % Better table layouts
    \usepackage[journal=rsc]{chemstyle} % Of course!
    \usepackage{geometry} % Easy page layout
    \usepackage{lmodern} % Use Latin Modern fonts
    \usepackage[version=3]{mhchem} % Formula subscripts using \ce{}
    \usepackage{xkeyval}
    \usepackage{pst-pdf}
    \usepackage{ifplatform}

    \begin{document}
    Test Test
    \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \psfrag{goldhydrid}{test}
    \includegraphics[scale=1.0]{./goldhydrid}
    \caption{A Caption}
    \label{fig:goldhydrid}
    \end{figure}

    \end{document}
```

But I get an error saying:

"Could not create test-pics.pdf. Auxiliary files not deleted."

---

Ok, after playing around for a while, I could make it work through changing to

```
    \usepackage[crop=off]{auto-pst-pdf}
```

I also found, that if you're using an EPS file with a text to be substituted by `chemnum` or `psfrag` directly, that is very close to the borders of the EPS file, then you might get in trouble with it, because parts of the new text will be cut off. This problem obviously only occurs, if you are using `pdflatex` but not, if you're using the EPS files directly with a `latex`->`dvi`->`ps`->`pdf` workflow.

Cheers,
Vlad

Comment: The package [`auto-pst-pdf`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/auto-pst-pdf) enables to use `psfrag` (the package that is used by `chemnum` internally for placing the numbers in the EPS files) with pdflatex

Comment: Can you describe that in a bit more detail? I tried to use this, but didn't get any proper results..

Comment: I always put `\usepackage[runs=2]{auto-pst-pdf}` in my premable and the compile with shell-escape enabled

Comment: that's what I do in this case, too.. but it still doesn't work, apparently.

Comment: Did you run pdflatex with _shell-escape_ enabled?

Comment: yes I did. The solution was to turning this on: \usepackage[crop=off]{auto-pst-pdf}